# Android ListView adapter behaviour

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I have total 9 rows. I want to change text style in only one row, for example in a row, which TextView text equals "Disabled". When i set text style for this row, it affects 3 more rows. In Result i have 4 rows which TextView text is bold. What kind of problem is it?

Comment: post your adapter getView() method

Comment: it has more than 100 lines of code. There are a lot of another View inside. I just want to know principle of that behaviour.

Comment: My guess is that you aren't handling the View recycling properly so your style is getting applied to lines it is not supposed to because those rows are using recycled TextViews. But if you are unwilling to post your code then It would be impossible to be more specific, and this question probably would fall under "Too localized" since it is unlikely that anyone in the future could get any help from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ListView adapter Views are reused or recycled. In your code, set it to your special textStyle when "Disabled" and to default when not.

Comment: Thank you, that works, i forgot about default behaviour. I will accept this answer asap. Can't accept it in 7 minutes.